# How to show Imageview ,textView and Title on Toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have with my toolbar xml file which show how does my toolbar look Like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="65dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:id="@+id/showevents"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/cart"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/showevents"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/showevents"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my Activity code to access Toolbar:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Product Details");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

my Question is that Image and text both are shown on toolbar but why Title is     not showing.is there any way to show the title? Any help would be appreciated in advanced..

Comment: if u r custmizing the toolbar then u have to add Title in RelativeLayout too and set it from der.

Comment: Thanks kevz it works ,it save my time

Answer (score 0):

if you are customizing the toolbar then customize completely. Add one more text view in relative layout for title and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled to false.